# Unity, Multiple custom editors for the same type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I'm making a plugin based C# application in Unity 5.6, where some plugins might sometimes be installed, sometimes not.

In my plugin `Plugin1`, I have a component `Plugin1.Component1`. In that same project, I implement a custom editor for it, called `Plugin1.Component1Editor`, that is a `[CustomEditor(typeof(Plugin1.Component1))]`. When `Plugin1` is installed, the `Component1` is available, and rendered with the custom editor.

My plugin `Plugin2` depends on `Plugin1`. Depending on settings in its component `Plugin2.Component2`, it would like to alter the custom editor for `Plugin1.Component1`.

I have implemented a new custom editor in `Plugin2`, called `Plugin2.Component1Editor`, that is also a `[CustomEditor(typeof(Plugin1.Component1))]`. It inherits from `UnityEditor.Editor`, not from `Plugin1.Component1Editor`, as the latter caused problems with serialized properties not being found in `Plugin1.Component1Editor`.

`Plugin2.Component1Editor` won't collide with `Plugin1.Component1Editor` at compile time, as it has its own namespace. But what actually happens in the Unity inspector?

The behaviour when I test it is the desired behaviour: The `Plugin2.Component1Editor` renders the inspector, unless `Plugin2` not installed. But why?
I don't want to trust that it will keep doing so unless I know why.

Thank you!

EDIT: I was wrong, it wasn't rendering the `Plugin2.Component1Editor`, it was the default Unity editor running. Neither of my custom editors are used. How can I specify which one I want to use?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the solution was indeed inheritance.

I made the serialized properties handled by `Plugin1.Component1Editor` and their retrieval protected instead of private, and then `Plugin2.Component1Editor` inherits from `Plugin1.Component1Editor` instead of `UnityEditor.Editor`. Then the `Plugin2.Component1Editor` became the rendering one, calling the `Plugin1.Component1Editor` as needed.

The main part of the solution was that I made the `OnEnable` call in `Plugin1.Component1Editor`, which retrieves the serialized properties, protected, so that I could call it from `Plugin2.Component1Editor` via `base.OnEnable()`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling on this question, the OP's solution only works (for me at least) if you have Plugin1 and Plugin2, where as if you have Plugin3 the last plugin will not be loaded as a custom editor. So i came up with another solution to this.

I've decided to use an "Editor Hub", a custom editor for `Component1`, that looks for `ICustomEditor` interface implementations using `System.Reflection`, also Unity has a nice class like `TypeCache` which can get you loaded classes

```
    public interface ICustomEditor
    {
        EditorType Type { get; }
        void OnEnable(SerializedObject target);
        void OnInspectorGUI(SerializedObject target);
    }
```

I've decided to go for `EditorType.Before` or `EditorType.After` to render custom features before or after the main editor.

```
    protected virtual void OnEnable()
    {
        CollectEditors();
        OnEnableEditors();
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        OnInspectorGUIBefore();
        base.OnInspectorGUI();
        OnInspectorGUIAfter();
    }

    private void CollectEditors()
    {
        var types = TypeCache.GetTypesDerivedFrom(typeof(ICustomEditor));

        var list = new List<ICustomEditor>();

        foreach (var e in types)
        {
            var editor = (ICustomEditor)Activator.CreateInstance(e);
            list.Add(editor);
        }

        m_beforeEditors = list
            .Where(t => t.Type == EditorType.Before)
            .ToArray();

        m_afterEditors = list
            .Where(t => t.Type == EditorType.After)
            .ToArray();
    }
```